# MySQL error when creating field schema

Tags: 7, entities

I have a problem when adding a new field to a content type. The schema installer for the specified field always causes the following error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`, `entity_id`, `deleted`, `delta`,' at line 12.

Here is the `hook_field_schema()` implementation:

```
function google_directions_field_schema($field)
{
    return array(
        'columns' => array(
            'lat' => array(
                'type' => 'float',
                'size' => 'big',
                'not null' => false,
            ),
            'lng' => array(
                'type' => 'float',
                'size' => 'big',
                'not null' => false,
            ),
            'mapTypeId' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => '15',
                'not null' => false,
            ),
            'zoom' => array(
                'type' => 'integer',
                'size' => 'small',
                'not null' => false,
            ),
        ),
        'indexes' => array(
            'lat_lng' => array('lat', 'lng'),
        ),
    );
}
```

I hope somebody can point out my mistake here. If some informations missing, please comment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please create transfer your 'edit' to your own answer, then except it.  If you don't then the site will think this is an unanswered question

Comment: Okay, sorry. Thought that would be too selfish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by myself. Please note the mistyped column type name `integer` which is now `int`:

```
function google_directions_field_schema($field)
{
    return array(
        'columns' => array(
            'lat' => array(
                'type' => 'float',
                'size' => 'big',
                'not null' => false,
            ),
            'lng' => array(
                'type' => 'float',
                'size' => 'big',
                'not null' => false,
            ),
            'mapTypeId' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => '15',
                'not null' => false,
            ),
            'zoom' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'size' => 'small',
                'not null' => false,
            ),
        ),
        'indexes' => array(
            'lat_lng' => array('lat', 'lng'),
        ),
    );
}
```